Posterior's impact of changing parameter's support
Let's say I'm doing Bayesian inference and I have a parameter $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. I'm doing MCMC with Metropolis Algorithm and for this I consider the transformation $\psi = \log(\alpha/(1 - \alpha))$, with prior $\psi \sim \text{Normal}(0, 100)$, but I still have interest in $\alpha$ (credibility intervals, HPD intervals, etc).
Can I sample for $\psi$ using a Metropolis Algorithm and then transform each sample such that $\alpha = 1/(1 + \exp(-\psi))$? When should I care for computing the Jacobian of the transformation?

"$\psi$" and "$\alpha$" are just two mathematically equivalent names for the same thing.  Jacobians come in when you are working with densities, as explained (inter alia) in such threads as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093 and (in a more elementary fashion) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.

I know that in the likelihood I can safely switch $\alpha$ for $1/(1 + \exp(-\psi))$.
Does this mean that I can do the same in the posterior distribution, sample $\psi$ with Metropolis and then transform to get my estimates for $\alpha$?

The Jacobian transform applies to the prior/posterior, not to the likelihood.

Yes, but If I consider $\psi = \log(\alpha/(1-\alpha))$, may I use a normal prior for $\psi$ and go on with the calculations, sampling $\psi$ with Metropolis Algorithm and re-transform the sampled values to get samples from $\alpha$?

To elaborate on my previous comment: if you want to sample a person's weight from a population, you select the person randomly and find out their weight.  You may, if you find it convenient, originally express that weight in pounds and later convert that weight to kilograms.  Although the population distributions of kilos and weights differ, there is no problem with this procedure.

The plain answer is yes : constructing a Markov chain for the $\psi$ parameterisation of the model and transforming the chain values in $\alpha$ values does produce an MCMC sample from the posterior distribution of $\alpha$ given the data. This applies in particular to the derivation of credible intervals on $\alpha$.

@Xi'an: That looks like an answer, can you make it one?

Possible duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567724/can-i-transform-a-parameters-posterior-to-a-different-parametrization

When a model parameter $\psi$ is transformed into another $\alpha=T(\psi)$, an identically distributed sample $\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_N$ from a given distribution on $\psi$, $\pi_\psi(\psi)$ say, can be transformed into a sample
$$\alpha_1=T(\psi_1),\ldots,\alpha_N=T(\psi_N)$$
that follows the "push-forward" distribution $T_\#\pi_\psi$. If the density of $T_\#\pi_\psi$ need be expressed, and if the transform $T(\cdot)$ is invertible, then the standard Jacobian formula applies:
$$\pi_\alpha(\alpha)=\pi_\psi(T^{-1}(\alpha))\left|\dfrac{\text dT^{-1}(\alpha)}{\text d\alpha}\right|$$
Concerning credible regions, if $A^\beta$ is a credible region on $\psi$, with $\pi_\psi(\psi\in A^\beta)=\beta$ then $T(A^\beta)$ is a credible region on $\alpha$ at the same level $\beta$. Note however that, when $A^\beta$ is an HPD region on $\psi$, $T(A^\beta)$ is not necessarily an HPD region on $\alpha$, because of the (interference of the) Jacobian.
